# C++: How to cin input into an object after instantiating with default constructor when the class is templatized

Tags: c++, templates, input, default-constructor, class-template

**Introduction:**

Sorry if the title is a little confusing or vague. It's been very difficult to do an internet search on my problem because the question I have doesn't seem to break down into searchable terms. Also, this is my first post on Stackoverflow, if I go outside of the conventionalism of posting questions, please bear with me, I'll do the best I can formatting wise.

**With that said, let me go into what I'm trying to do:**

I am a student at a college working on an assignment given from the instructor. We're creating a class for vectors(that is, vectors in terms of mathematics, not the data type vector). This class is to be a class template, two different templated datatypes, one for the x component of a vector, and the other for y component of a vector. It's a simple class, the class returns the magnitude and direction (in radians) of a vector. There are also overloaded input and output operators as friend functions, and a couple of constructors. I'm not working with dynamic memory, so we can put that whole can of worms aside.

**Here's the problem I am having:**

```
Vector2D<int, int> vec1(); //Default Constructor
cin  >> vec1;
cout << "\nVector 1 = " << vec1 << "\n\tDirection: " << vec1.direction()
     << "\tMagnitude: " << vec1.magnitude() << "\n\n";
```

My problem is, I am unable to do a cin, and I'm unable to output direction() and magnitude(). The compiler gives me a really long error, but basically says

error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

If, however, I do this:

```
Vector2D<int, int> vec1(0,0); //No longer the default constructor
cin  >> vec1;
cout << "\nVector 1 = " << vec1 << "\n\tDirection: " << vec1.direction()
     << "\tMagnitude: " << vec1.magnitude() << "\n\n";
```

All is happy with the world. Therefore, my question is simply, how do I fix this? I would like to use cin after I instantiate with a default constructor, and I would like to output the direction() and magnitude(). Consider I've done all my header declarations and everything else right, and that the way I wrote my class is wrong -- here it is:

**My class file:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>    //for sqrt function to get the magnitude and atan for radians.

using namespace std;

template <class T, class S>
class Vector2D
{
private:
    T m_xComp;
    S m_yComp;
    static int signif_digit; //Becomes the argument for setPrecision(x) on output.
public:
    static int signif_digits;
    Vector2D(): m_xComp((T)0), (S)m_yComp((S)0) {};
    Vector2D(T xComp, S yComp);
    void setX(T xComp);
    void setY(S yComp);
    T getX();
    S getY();
    double magnitude();
    double direction(); //returns direction of vector in radians.
    static void setPrecision(int prec);
    static int precision();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector2D<T,S>& vec)
    { //A good thing to figure out: Why did I have to declare friend functions in line?
        os  << '<' << vec.m_xComp << ',' << vec.m_yComp << '>';
        return os;
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Vector2D<T,S>& vec)
    { //A good thing to figure out: Why did I have to declare friend functions in line?
        char remove_Char;
        T xComp = 0;
        S yComp = 0;
        is >> remove_Char >> xComp >> remove_Char >> yComp;
        vec.m_xComp = xComp;
        vec.m_yComp = yComp;
        return is;
    }
};


template <class T, class S>
Vector2D<T, S>::Vector2D(T xComp, S yComp)
{
    m_xComp = xComp;
    m_yComp = yComp;
}


template <class T, class S>
void Vector2D<T, S>::setPrecision(int prec)
{
    signif_digit = prec;
}


template <class T, class S>
int Vector2D<T, S>::precision()
{   return signif_digit;    }


template <class T, class S>
void Vector2D<T, S>::setX(T xComp)
{   m_xComp = xComp;    }


template <class T, class S>
void Vector2D<T, S>::setY(S yComp)
{   m_yComp = yComp;    }


template <class T, class S>
T Vector2D<T, S>::getX()
{   return m_xComp;     }


template <class T, class S>
S Vector2D<T, S>::getY()
{   return m_yComp;     }


template <class T, class S>
double Vector2D<T, S>::magnitude()
{
    return sqrt( (double)(m_xComp*m_xComp + m_yComp*m_yComp) );
}


//------------------------Consider using atan2 next time-------------------------------------
template <class T, class S>
double Vector2D<T, S>::direction()
{
    if (m_xComp == 0)
    {
        if(m_yComp == 0)
        {
            cout << "\nNote: Both x and y components equal zero.\n";
            return 0;
        }
        else if (m_yComp > 0)
            return atan(1.0)*2; //If y > 0 and x = 0, return PI/2
        else if (m_yComp < 0)
            return atan(1.0)*6; //If y < 0 and x = 0, return 3*PI/2
    }
    else if (m_xComp > 0)
    {
        if (m_yComp >= 0)
            return atan((double)(m_yComp/m_xComp)); //First Quadrant
        else
            return (atan(1.0)*8 + atan((double)(m_yComp/m_xComp)) ); //Fourth Quadrant
    }
    else
        return (atan(1.0)*4 + atan((double)(m_yComp/m_xComp)) ); //Second & Third Quadrant
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


template <class T, class S>
int Vector2D<T, S>::signif_digit = 3;   //private

template <class T, class S>
int Vector2D<T, S>::signif_digits = 3;  //public
```

That is all. Please let me know if there is any additional information I need to include.

Thanks.

Comment: `Vector2D<int, int> vec1(); ` this declares a function. Search for "most vexing parse", and leave out the `()` to fix it; or change them to `{}`.

Comment: You should *always* add a language tag. This will also provide automatic syntax highlighting.

Comment: `using namespace std;` Please don't do that in a header file. It's bad practice and can introduce problems eventually (name clashes).

Comment: `//A good thing to figure out: Why did I have to declare friend functions in line?` I guess you mean *define*, i.e. *why did I have to put the function body of the friend function inside the class template definition/body?* Because that's the easiest and safest thing to do. You can also define it outside the class, but then you should use forward-declarations (as friend declarations are declarations and can introduce new names, this can lead to subtle issues).

Comment: Some of those member functions can be `const` (which means that you *should* declare them as `const`). Such concerns can be address at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @dyp Something I should have noticed long ago. Hate asking obvious questions. I'm so surprised at myself.

Comment: @dyp Also, I will try to make sure I add a tag next time, sorry for that inconvenience.

Comment: @dyp I will be much more aware of the using namespace std; the instructor tends to like us using it, so it will stay for now.

Comment: @dyp What I meant about declaring friend functions in line, was indeed about defining them, but also, I was wondering why I had to do it inline, because when I tried to define them outside the class, it wouldn't allow me to do it. Of course, I could have defined them wrong, but hey, declaring them inline is fine with me as long as they work.

Comment: @Dyp, thank you, you've given me so many other tips as well, I really appreciate them. You're right about the const by the way.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, dyp answers my question. It was so simple. Merely, I was trying to instantiate the MyVector class like I was declaring a function.

This code:

```
Vector2D<int, int> vec1();
```

Should have been:

```
Vector2D<int, int> vec1;
```

Easy as cake. Thanks again, dyp.